# Scrapy (python) only collecting 75% of target web pages - how to improve

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to collect about 150 attributes for Cloud Services listed on the UK Gov Digital Marketplace (G-Cloud). The catalogue holds details of about 40,000 services accessed through summary pages with 30 products to a page (1,355 pages). Things have been going fine for 5 or 6 years. Now the catalogue has been moved to a new URL. I have repaired all the Xpaths and tested and I am getting all the data I need when a product is hit.

But comparing my downloaded product count to the total on the catalogue, I am getting only 30,000 products - missing 25%.

"custom_settings" includes 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': .5,
'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': 60,

1. Would changing these settings improve my harvest?
2. What else can you suggest may be impacting my low yield?

For completeness, here is the pagination function, which seems to work effectively, so I don't think the fault lies here:

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//h2/a/@href').getall():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_item)

        next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="dm-pagination__item dm-pagination__item--next"]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

Historically, I never get the full product count as a small number are suspended for editing or deletion. But this would be less then 1%. The script takes roughly 15 hours to run from my desktop. I am running the script repeatedly to see if the outcome is consistent and if the missing products are always the same ones. Due to the long run-time it will be a week or so before I have sufficient data to draw a conclusion.

Comment: Could you please give the url u r looking for scrape? Try this one xpath on next_page variable **response.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'next')]/@href").get()** .

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here are the top urls (I run three in a .bat file):     start_urls = ['https://www.applytosupply.digitalmarketplace.service.gov.uk/g-cloud/search?lot=cloud-software']
    # start_urls = ['https://www.applytosupply.digitalmarketplace.service.gov.uk/g-cloud/search?lot=cloud-support']
    # start_urls = ['https://www.applytosupply.digitalmarketplace.service.gov.uk/g-cloud/search?lot=cloud-hosting']

Comment: Very interested in your suggested line, I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: I have re-run this Scrapy several times in the last week without changing the code. The last run drew a perfect yield with less than 30 of the 40,000 services missing. I can identify that the problem only affected one URL and assume there was some problem on the website, perhaps traffic slowed response times and Scrapy moved on. So problem solved.